# aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc Cross Complier for arm fails

Tags: c, ubuntu, makefile, pjsip

```
./configure --host=arm-elf-linux  CC=aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc --disable-sdl --disable-ffmpeg --disable-v4l2 --disable-openh264 --disable-libwebrtc --disable-libyuv

make dep && make
```

"**file in wrong  format**"   Err:

```
$ file main.o 
main.o: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64,

$file other *.o
sip_uri.o: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, ARM aarch64,
```

so main.o file format is **x86-64**  , but other .o files  formate are **ARM aarch64**

but ....i still dont know how to solve that ( change the main.o file format)

**the segment of main.o in Makefile and i m sure the Problem at line:287**

```
# Defines for building pjsua2-test application
161 #
162 export PJSUA2_TEST_SRCDIR = ../src/pjsua2-test
163 export PJSUA2_TEST_OBJS += $(OS_OBJS) $(M_OBJS) $(CC_OBJS) $(HOST_OBJS) \
164          main.o
165 export PJSUA2_TEST_CFLAGS += $(_CFLAGS) $(PJ_VIDEO_CFLAGS)
166 export PJSUA2_TEST_CXXFLAGS = $(_CXXFLAGS) $(PJSUA2_LIB_CFLAGS) $(PJ_VIDEO_CFLAGS)
167 export PJSUA2_TEST_LDFLAGS += $(PJ_LDXXFLAGS) $(PJ_LDXXLIBS) $(LDFLAGS)
168 ifeq ($(EXCLUDE_APP),0)
169 export PJSUA2_TEST_EXE := pjsua2-test-$(TARGET_NAME)$(HOST_EXE)
170 endif
171 export CC_OUT CC AR RANLIB HOST_MV HOST_RM HOST_RMDIR HOST_MKDIR OBJEXT LD LDOUT
----------------------
pjsua2-test: $(PJSUA2_TEST_EXE)
281 $(PJSUA2_TEST_EXE): $(PJSIP_LIB) $(PJSIP_SONAME)
282 $(PJSUA2_TEST_EXE): $(PJSIP_UA_LIB) $(PJSIP_UA_SONAME)
283 $(PJSUA2_TEST_EXE): $(PJSIP_SIMPLE_LIB) $(PJSIP_SIMPLE_SONAME)
284 $(PJSUA2_TEST_EXE): $(PJSUA_LIB_LIB) $(PJSUA_LIB_SONAME)
285 $(PJSUA2_TEST_EXE): $(PJSUA2_LIB_LIB) $(PJSUA2_LIB_SONAME)
286 $(PJSUA2_TEST_EXE):
287   **$(MAKE) -f $(RULES_MAK) APP=PJSUA2_TEST app=pjsua2-test $(subst /,$(HOST_PSEP),$(BINDIR)/$@)**
```

**the makefile err message**

```
mkdir -p output/pjsua2-test-aarch64-linux-gnu/
g++ -c  -DPJ_AUTOCONF=1 -g -O2    -Wall -DPJ_AUTOCONF=1 -O2 -DPJ_IS_BIG_ENDIAN=0 -DPJ_IS_LITTLE_ENDIAN=1    -I../include -I../../pjlib/include -I../../pjlib-util/include -I../../pjnath/include -I../../pjmedia/include -Wall -DPJ_AUTOCONF=1 -O2 -DPJ_IS_BIG_ENDIAN=0 -DPJ_IS_LITTLE_ENDIAN=1    -I../include -I../../pjlib/include -I../../pjlib-util/include -I../../pjnath/include -I../../pjmedia/include                                 \
    -o output/pjsua2-test-aarch64-linux-gnu/main.o \
    ../src/pjsua2-test/main.cpp
../src/pjsua2-test/main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
../src/pjsua2-test/main.cpp:27:9: warning: division by zero [-Wdiv-by-zero]
   27 |    k = 1/0;
      |        ~^~
../src/pjsua2-test/main.cpp:26:7: warning: variable ‘k’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   26 |   int k =1;
      |       ^
if test ! -d ../bin; then mkdir -p ../bin; fi
aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -o ../bin/pjsua2-test-aarch64-linux-gnu \
     output/pjsua2-test-aarch64-linux-gnu/main.o -L/home/duma/Public/pjproject2/pjlib/lib -L/home/duma/Public/pjproject2/pjlib-util/lib -L/home/duma/Public/pjproject2/pjnath/lib -L/home/duma/Public/pjproject2/pjmedia/lib -L/home/duma/Public/pjproject2/pjsip/lib -L/home/duma/Public/pjproject2/third_party/lib              -lpjsua2-aarch64-linux-gnu -lstdc++ -lpjsua-aarch64-linux-gnu -lpjsip-ua-aarch64-linux-gnu -lpjsip-simple-aarch64-linux-gnu -lpjsip-aarch64-linux-gnu -lpjmedia-codec-aarch64-linux-gnu -lpjmedia-aarch64-linux-gnu -lpjmedia-videodev-aarch64-linux-gnu -lpjmedia-audiodev-aarch64-linux-gnu -lpjmedia-aarch64-linux-gnu -lpjnath-aarch64-linux-gnu -lpjlib-util-aarch64-linux-gnu  -lsrtp-aarch64-linux-gnu -lresample-aarch64-linux-gnu -lgsmcodec-aarch64-linux-gnu -lspeex-aarch64-linux-gnu -lilbccodec-aarch64-linux-gnu -lg7221codec-aarch64-linux-gnu  -lpj-aarch64-linux-gnu -lm -lrt -lpthread  
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: output/pjsua2-test-aarch64-linux-gnu/main.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 62)
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: output/pjsua2-test-aarch64-linux-gnu/main.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 62)
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: output/pjsua2-test-aarch64-linux-gnu/main.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 62)
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: output/pjsua2-test-aarch64-linux-gnu/main.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 62)
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: output/pjsua2-test-aarch64-linux-gnu/main.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 62)
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: output/pjsua2-test-aarch64-linux-gnu/main.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 62)
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: output/pjsua2-test-aarch64-linux-gnu/main.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 62)
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: output/pjsua2-test-aarch64-linux-gnu/main.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 62)
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: output/pjsua2-test-aarch64-linux-gnu/main.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 62)
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: output/pjsua2-test-aarch64-linux-gnu/main.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 62)
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: output/pjsua2-test-aarch64-linux-gnu/main.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 62)
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: output/pjsua2-test-aarch64-linux-gnu/main.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 62)
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: output/pjsua2-test-aarch64-linux-gnu/main.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 62)
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: output/pjsua2-test-aarch64-linux-gnu/main.o: error adding symbols: file in wrong format
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/duma/Public/pjproject2/build/rules.mak:125: ../bin/pjsua2-test-aarch64-linux-gnu] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/duma/Public/pjproject2/pjsip/build'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:287: pjsua2-test-aarch64-linux-gnu] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/duma/Public/pjproject2/pjsip/build'
make: *** [Makefile:14: all] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the libraries to link may not be built with the same toolchain.  You can check with `objdump`.

Example (The "file format" may not be the exact result in your case):

```
$ aarch64-linux-gnu-objdump -TC libz.so

libz.so:     file format elf64-littleaarch64
```

Please confirm that the "file format" of **all the libraries** should match your toolchain.

Update:

You can see the compliling message for main.cpp when `make`

**g++** -c  -DPJ_AUTOCONF=1 -g -O2    -Wall -DPJ_AUTOCONF=1 -O2 -DPJ_IS_BIG_ENDIAN=0 -DPJ_IS_LITTLE_ENDIAN=1    -I../include -I../../pjlib/include -I../../pjlib-util/include -I../../pjnath/include -I../../pjmedia/include -Wall -DPJ_AUTOCONF=1 -O2 -DPJ_IS_BIG_ENDIAN=0 -DPJ_IS_LITTLE_ENDIAN=1    -I../include -I../../pjlib/include -I../../pjlib-util/include -I../../pjnath/include -I../../pjmedia/include                                 
-o output/pjsua2-test-aarch64-linux-gnu/main.o 
../src/pjsua2-test/main.cpp

It should not be `g++`. It should be `aarch64-linux-gnu-g++`.

Please try the following steps:

1. Add `CXX=aarch64-linux-gnu-g++` in configure command line and run again
2. Confirm your makefile will use `$(CXX)` to compile cpp files, not `g++`

Comment: Thx for reply!   the main.o format is elf64-little

Comment: and other .o files  format are elf64-littleaarch64

Comment: ``make clean`` then ``make`` again. If it still doesn't work, check how to you compile main.c in makefile.

Comment: thanks again. i have post the Makfile section of main.o   below

Comment: Any additional information should be added to your question (using "Edit",) not the answer part.


The makefile section you provided cannot provide enough information for how to build main.o.  Please check whether ``main.o`` will be removed after ``make clean``


If yes, a debug trick is to add some code segment that will generate compiling error definitely in main.c/cpp. And check the ouput error message to find out how it to be compiled.

Comment: got it~ ah , yes im sure the main.o will be rmeoved after make clean. and i add division by zero err in main.cpp.  i have update the message, check plz

Comment: @SleepyCat Check the update in my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much bro!  thx